# Keys all switched on keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, keymap, function-keys

My friend/enemy switched the keys on my keyboard as an April fool's joke. When I press Y, Z appears on the screen. Some keys work like b, x, g, i, d, and a few more. Also, when I press ctrl, it returns Enter. Even the function keys are switched!!

I called a technician and even he wasn't able to detect the issue and told me installing the operating system was the only go. I really don't want to call up my friend and ask him.

I'm on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and there is no problem with my mouse. (Thank God)

Can you help me?

Comment: System restore to 31st March.

Comment: Check for things like AutoHotKey running

Comment: "I really don't want to call up my friend and ask him" Why not? Go visit him and take your baseball bat ;)

Comment: Nothing suspicious is running.

Comment: Also check regional settings in the control panel and make sure they didnt switch it to another language. There is a default hotkey in windows (Left Alt- Shift) that changes this, and that was colliding with some of my visual studio shortcuts causing my keyboard to switch in mid-code.

Comment: Physically swap the keys on your keyboard to their (now) correct locations, and then spend the next few days adapting to your new non-QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: Start locking your workstation when you walk away!

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but I have to ask... Are you sure he didn't just pop the caps off the keys and physically move them?  A co-worker had this happen to him and he didn't realize it because he is a "hunt and peck" typist.

Comment: @James Nah, he didn't swap the keys physically. If he did, I would have gone to his house with a baseball bat and made him buy a new keyboard for me lol.

Comment: The real question here is: how did you type this question?

Comment: Google Services. I spent 10 seconds thinking why would anyone choose this username

Comment: @Braiam I typed it from my laptop...I don't have my desktop computer only...

Comment: @dotancohen For sure, from now onwards.

Comment: @gopi1410 Why mate? Seems okay...

Comment: Featured at How-to Geek : http://www.howtogeek.com/250021/how-do-you-reset-a-keyboards-mapping-after-an-april-fools-prank-wrecks-it/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For the simple case, it sounds like you have a different keyboard layout (e.g German, as that swaps Y and Z).

Change layouts in Control Panel:

1. "Clock, Language, and Region"
2. "Region and Language "
3. "Keyboards and Languages" tab, -> "Change keyboards"

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch layouts.

However this does not explain function keys. It's possible to arbitrarily remap keys using the registry. I think you'll need a 3rd party tool to fix this. 
Example: https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

Remember you can use the "On screen keyboard" (Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Ease of Access\On screen keyboard) to type with the mouse.

Comment: And what if <alt> and <shift> have been remapped? ;)

Comment: Another way to get to the on-screen keyboard is to press the Windows logo key+U... if you can figure out where those are.  That will bring up the Ease of Access "Utility" menu with a link to the keyboard.

Comment: Yep, the left alt is mapped to U and the right one is mapped to shift itself I think. Anyway, I tried sharpkeys and started mapping keys to the right ones.

Comment: @GoogleServices You can use a virtual keyboard while your physical one is being fixed. That way you'll type with your mouse and wont have any keyboard issues.

Answer (score 44):

If you don't want to use any third-party applications to reverse the SharpKeys modifications, you can cut out the middleman and edit the Registry directly.

Open the Registry Editor by navigating to `C:\Windows\regedit.exe` in Explorer. Once it's open, navigate here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

If there are entries called `Scancode Map` or `Value Scancode Map`, delete them. Those are what cause Windows to remap incoming keypresses from the keyboard.

Once you're done, reboot. Key remappings will be reset to the default. You can do all of this with the mouse only, no keyboard.

References for those IDs: [`Main.cs` in the SharpKeys source code](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpKeys/Dialog_Main.cs), ["How to Disable the Insert Key in Windows" from WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-the-Insert-Key-in-Windows).

Answer (score 14):

It's worth checking for processes running in the background which manipulate your key entry. I use AutoHotkey scripts to add/override some keybindings. They generally appear in the system tray as a little green icon with a capital 'H'.

If you can't find the process there, you can also check the 'startup' folder in your start menu to see if they have added something to run when you log on.